# Explain diff between TestNG Object[][] data provider VS. Iterable<Object[]> data provider?

Tags: testng

Can anyone explain the difference between a Object[][] DataProvider  vs.  an Iterable DataProvider?

The TestNG documentation, says the following, but it's not clear enough for me.   I have always used the Object[][] method because the explanation of the Iterator  method is kindof cryptic and hard to understand what he really means in the paragraph.

```
The Data Provider method can return one of the following two types:

  - An array of array of objects (Object[][]) where the first dimension's size is 
    the number of times the test method will be invoked and the second dimension
    size contains an array of objects that must be compatible with the parameter 
    types of the test method. This is the cast illustrated by the example above.

  - An Iterator<Object[]>. The only difference with Object[][] is that an Iterator
    lets you create your test data lazily. TestNG will invoke the iterator and then
    the test method with the parameters returned by this iterator one by one. This is
    particularly useful if you have a lot of parameter sets to pass to the method and 
    you don't want to create all of them upfront.
```

I asked this question here but not sure if I will get an answer there:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/NgZrMfprriY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterator would basically be used if your data setup step is time-consuming.

Let's assume you are reading data from an excel, based on which you are doing some processing to generate data - probably invoking a webservice or another io operation.  If the processing takes 2 seconds per data and considering you have 200 data,

1. With Object[][], your first test would run after 400 seconds after all data has been generated
2. With iterator, if you move your processing logic to next() method, your first test starts after 2 seconds, the test executes and then the next data setup takes place.

So, the choice basically depends on how you want your tests structured if your datasetup is long.

Comment: So, it sounds like TestNG automatically handles the call to next() for me?   So, the DataProvider will block and hand out parameters as they come in from the data source?   So, test instances will start as they come available right?

Comment: Yes, TestNG handles the call to next after each test finishes.

Comment: It all makes perfect sense to me now.   I hate that I can't see some of the TestNG source code so I can see how this stuff works.  I browsed the source code in the GitHub TestNG repo and it seems to be missing some stuff?  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple rule:

Using Object[][] whenever I can because test cases can be formatted on nice and readable way:

```
private static final String LOWERCASE_Y = "y";
private static final String UPPERCASE_Y = "Y";
private static final String STUDENT = "Student";

@DataProvider
public final Object[][] testCases() {
    //@formatter:off
    return new Object [][]{
        { null, UPPERCASE_Y },
        { null, LOWERCASE_Y },
        { StringUtils.EMPTY, LOWERCASE_Y },
        { StringUtils.EMPTY, UPPERCASE_Y },
        { STUDENT, UPPERCASE_Y },
        { STUDENT, LOWERCASE_Y },
    };
    //@formatter:on
}
```

This is sometimes not suitable (e.g. you have dynamical test cases or they need to be generated). In such case you can just feed some collection with test cases and return iterator. But I use this rarely.